# Making ReSharper suggestions logical once again

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

I'm really happy to have Resharper with me, when coding, but sometimes the suggestions and preselected values in the Autopopup, is just.... ridiculous.

Take these examples:

## Return statement should be the obvious choice, right?

[image: return statement]

## Enums are not suggested, even though it's also the most obvious.

[image: enums not suggested]

How do I make ReSharper stop being an idiot? I want the most obvious suggestions when I hit space, hit dot (.) etc.; the suggestions shown above has nothing to do with the code I'm about to write.

If I want smart completion or smart import completion, I hit CTRL+SPACE, CTRL+SHIFT+SPACE or CTRL+ALT+SPACE.

## EDIT

[image: settings]

Comment: Have you checked the settings on the completion behavior settings page under Environment, Intellisense?

Comment: Type one more letter for return and be happy that you have resharper to be a lazy programmer, don't become lazier and the second image what do you want resharper to magically do there?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen - I've added a screenshot of my settings. Disabling most of it, doesn't help at all.

Comment: @KevinCrain - It's not a question of being lazy. It's a question of Resharper annoying the hell out of my coding habits. It's not very helpful to have `AppRelativeTemplateSourceDirectory` suggestion, when you'd think that inside an if-statement inside `Page_Load`, it would be most obvious to type `return`.

Comment: @KevinCrain - the second image shows that Resharper can't figure out enum types, even though it's really the only choice here. Enums can't be null, so the only type it should show is the enum `ListItemType`.

Comment: Okay yeah the enum thing is kind of not cool, may type a letter of the enum and see what happens

Comment: **Not able to reproduce**.  The `return` example works for me.  Resharper 8.1

Comment: @MickyDuncan - can you post a screenshot of your "Completion Behavior" settings?

Comment: @KristianB Sorry I didn't think to do that, one sec

Answer (score 1):

This may not be an answer but I include my **Completion Behavior** settings as requested.  I've spotted some differences in **Smart behavior**.

[image]

This is from **Resharper 8.1.23.546**